# What word would you use to indicate the type of a plant?

Tags: identification

I am making a webapplication that allows people to browse through a database full of plant information. People can also add filters before hitting the search button. One of those filters is now called 'plant type' and the options of the filter are `Plant`, `Bush`, `Tree`, `Fungus` and `Cactus`. If people select `Bush` and `Tree` for example they will retrieve only Bush and tree plants. Calling this filter 'Plant type' sounds a bit off and i was wondering whether there is a better term instead of **plant** to describe the list above. Does anyone know of a better or more appropiate word? Thank you

Comment: Plant type is fine - but if you want this app to sell worldwide, then 'bush' is a non specific term - shrub would be better. And what about perennials and herbaceous perennials, grasses, alpines and bulbs - they're not on your list of plant types. Not sure what you mean by 'plant' being one of the options either, its non specific - houseplant, maybe?

Comment: I am assuming this is a school/personal project? I agree with Bamboo 'plant type' is fine. If it sounds contrived that's because it is and as far as I am concerned that's as it should be.

Comment: To add to that, fungus aren't plants, they're.... Fungus (plural: Fungi) & they are MUCH more difficult to identify with any degree of safety than plants.
This [link has a few more terms](https://www.gardenia.net/plants/plant-types) you could add to your list of plant types though.

Comment: actually it is a website i hope to make money off, @Bamboo people can filter for perennial with the life cycle filter. With plant i mean anything smaller then a shrub, like a herb, or a tomato plant, or even a sunflower that can be harvested for seeds. I know a sunflower can grow higher then a shrub but i have to call it something, so i just call it plant. If you know of a better term please let me know, i would be very thankful

Comment: @renesis i know a fungus isn't a plant but say i would want to keep fungus in the list anyway, what term could i use best instead of `plant type`?

Comment: perhaps i should just call it `plant class` or just `class` instead, what do you think?

Comment: Nope - I order a lot of plants online in the UK - there are two or three ways to find plants on the sites, and one of the ways on all of them is 'plant type' - hit that button and up comes another list of choices - perennials, shrubs, alpines, bulbs and so on. Or you can put a plant name(latin name) in the search box and it will go straight to it, if they've got it.. But plant type is the correct terminology.Leave off fungi - they are not members of the Plant Kingdom, they are classified separately as  the Fungi Kingdom.

Comment: I know every plant has a latin name but does every plant variation have its own latin name too? For example, the tomato has the latin name `Solanum lycopersicum`, but do its varieties like `money maker` or `tiny tom` have its own latin names too? Because for each crop i am displaying different varieties.

Comment: i think i'll go for the word `herbaceous` to define anything that is not a shrub or a tree https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/herbaceous#herbaceous__1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think plant type is fine as long as you define filters for herbaceous, shrub, tree, cactus/succulent. As for including fungi (maybe you were thinking about mushrooms?) or lichens, you can define a more general filter called life form (plant, fungus, lichen, etc.) if you want to follow scientific classification. If you think the users don't care about scientific classification, you can still use plant type for fungi and lichens, maybe adding a disclaimer or something.

About latin names: commercial names of varieties such as "Red sunset" or whatever don't have a latin name. However, there are varieties/cultivars holding a latin epithet. For example, maybe it's not such a big deal if the app can not provide the exact variety of sunflower (let's say Helianthus annuus "Sunny red" and Helianthus annuus "Sunny yellow"), but it will be a big deal if it will not distinguish between broccoli (Brassica oleracea var. italica), cauliflower (Brassica oleracea var. botrytis), headed cabbage (Brassica oleracea var. capitata), kale (Brassica oleracea var. acephala) and Brussels sprouts (Brassica oleracea var. gemmifera).

As a general guideline, I think details in the name of a plant after the species term should be included if the information is known.

As far as I know, there is at least one mobile app for plant ID and you can check the reviews if its filters are intuitive or not so that you can change yours to not make the same mistakes when assuming the plant knowledge level of the users.

Comment: no im going to remove fungus. The target audience are vegetable and fruit gardeners. I don't think they will be too interested in growing mushrooms in their vegetable garden. Thanks for the info